# How can I see cucumber table differences with the progress formatter?

Tags: cucumber

In cucumber, when my table steps fail, I see the following error plus a stack trace, but there is no actual information given about the table differences.

`Tables were not identical (Cucumber::Ast::Table::Different)`

How can I get cucumber to show me the table differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following monkey patch worked on cucumber 1.1.9

Create a support file eg features/support/progress_formatter_extensions.rb

```rb
require 'cucumber/formatter/progress'

module Cucumber
  module Formatter
    class Progress
      def exception(exception, status)
        @exception_raised = true
        if exception.kind_of?(Cucumber::Ast::Table::Different)
          @io.puts(exception.table)
          @io.flush
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```